# Capturing output from an 'exec' task in CruiseControl.NET

Tags: .net, git, msbuild, cruisecontrol.net

I'm using CruiseControl.NET to build and version my code (format: major.minor.build.revision). For the revision version component, I used to use the SVN revision number. Now we're switching to Git, which uses SHA-1 hashes instead of revision numbers. After a quick internet search, I discovered that you can get the count of commits with the following command:

```
git rev-list HEAD --count
```

This command prints a number to stdout, then exits. This is the information that I need, but how do I capture that output in CCNET?

So far, I have this:

```
<tasks>
    <exec>
        <executable>git.exe</executable>
        <buildArgs>rev-list HEAD --count</buildArgs>
    </exec>
    <msbuild>
    ...
    </msbuild>
</tasks>
```

Answer (score 0):

Redirect this git command to a file.

```
git.exe rev-list HEAD --count >myRevision.txt
```

Then use **fileLabeller** in CC.NEt project configuration.

```
<labeller type="fileLabeller">
  <labelFilePath>myFolder\myRevision.txt</labelFilePath>
  <prefix>Foo-</prefix>
  <allowDuplicateSubsequentLabels>true</allowDuplicateSubsequentLabels>
</labeller>
```

Reference: 
http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/File_Labeller

Answer (score 0):

(Another solution)

Use the **GitTagLabeller** plugin.

> This labeller plugin builds the CCNet internal label from the last tag
>   on a git repository branch - usually downloaded using the git source
>   control provider.

https://github.com/TercerPlaneta/ccnet.GitTagLabeller